# Turning off logging in IBM DB2 9.7 LUW

Tags: logging, db2

I have problems with transaction logs becoming full when deploying to test environment. I have tried increasing log size, but I thought if it would be possible to disable logging all together then that would be even better. At least during the reset.

Apparently there is a command:

```
alter table table-name not logged initially;
```

But here one has to specify all tables individually. I am trying to find a way to do this:

```
1. turn off logging
2. delete all tables in schema
3. create/populate tables in schema
4. turn logging back on
```

I have points 2. and 3. covered, but not 1. and 4. The last point 4. is not even necessary in our test environment.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What you want is not possible. Consider using DB2 LOAD for populating your tables -- this will minimize logging.

Answer (score 1):

too many tables there? Automated script would be helpful to do repeated tasks:

```
db2 list tables for schema triuser | grep " T " |awk '{print "ALTER TABLE "$1" NOT LOGGED INITIALLY"}'
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this disables logging? yes, we have a lot of tables

Answer (score 0):

As cnZach has written, you have to generate a query from the information that you get. You can do that by querying the catalog, and then create a set of statements.

Following what you said, the statement to disable the logging in a specific table is

```
alter table table-name not logged initially;
```

But you have to retrieve all tables, or a set of tables from the database. This can be done by querying the catalog

```
db2 "select substr(tabschame) || '.' || substr(tabname) \
from syscat.table where type = 'T' and tabschema not like 'SYS%'"
```

Once you have modified the previous query to your requirements (retrieving the tables that you need), then you modify the query to generate the alter statement for all that tables

```
db2 "select 'alter table ' || substr(tabschame) || '.' \
|| substr(tabname) || ' not logger initially' \
from syscat.table where type = 'T' and tabschema not like 'SYS%'"
```

If you want, you can execute directly the db2 output, or just send that to a file and execute it later via "db2 -tvf filename.sql. The other option has a brawback, because there is a problem with the output size; if it is bigger that a limit, it cannot be executed ( | db2 +p -tv)

```
db2 "select 'alter table ' || substr(tabschame) || '.' \
|| substr(tabname) || ' not logger initially' \
from syscat.table where type = 'T' and tabschema not like 'SYS%'" | db2 +p -tv
```

Comment: Just remember that NOT LOGGED INITIALLY state has the unit of work scope -- as soon as a commit is issued, it is turned off. Since the DB2 command line processor has autocommit on by default, you will need to switch it off by using the `+c` command line option: `db2 +c -tvf filename.sql` and execute all your subsequent statements (steps 2 and 3 in your plan) in the same manner.

Comment: I would caution against using `NOT LOGGED INITIALLY` – if you have any failure, this will leave the table in an inoperable state and you will have to drop / recreate the table.